# How to swap first character with last character in ename column

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How to swap first character with last character in ename column from employee table. I amUsing EMP table default in SQL* plus

I have tried dual replace , but no success.

Ex : Smith is my name , my expected output is hmits

Comment: in SQL Server, you could do it with `declare @name nvarchar(10) = 'Smith'
select @name, Upper(right(@name, 1)) + RIGHT(@name, LEN(@name) - 1) + left(@name, 1)` ... not sure if oracle got those functions, but logic work both ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using substr() three times to fetch first, last and rest of the characters. And concatenate  them all

`select substr(ename,length (ename) )||
             substr(ename,2,length(ename)-2)||
             substr(ename,1,1)
from employee`

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can do:

```
select upper(substr(ename, -1)) || substr(ename, 2) || substr(ename, 1, 1)
from employee
```

This should be easy to put into an `update` if you want to actually change the data.

Comment: This doesn't work. Ex : Smith is my name , my expected output is HmitS